# Scrape job card details from INDEED website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from indeed website but I am having difficulties pulling data from Job cards on indeed.

I was able to build the URL successfully for Data analyst jobs in New york city. I did so like this ;

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
#from config import WebScrapingAPIkey
import sqlite3


search_job = 'Data analyst'
search_location = 'New York, NY'
job_age = 7

def make_indeed_url(search_job, search_location, job_age):
    '''
    This function takes in 3 search parameters and inserts them into an
    indeed.com url to search for jobs in those parameters
    input:
        search_job (str): job title being searched for
        search_location (str): city, state being searched
        job_age (int): 3 or 7, max age of job posting in days
    output:
        indeed_job_url (str): url to indeed jobs of the given parameters
    '''
    job = search_job.replace(' ', '+')
    location = search_location.replace(',', '%2C').replace(' ', '+')
    indeed_job_url = f'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={job}&l={location}&fromage={job_age}&vjk=d75084593b7d8230'
    return indeed_job_url
```

Thereafter I went ahead to create a function to pull data from INDEED job cards like this :

```
job_meta=make_indeed_url(search_job, search_location, job_age)

def scrape_job_card(job_meta):
    '''
    This function takes in a job_card_element from indeed.com and extracts the
    job title, company name, company location, and estimated salary
    input: 
        job_card_element, selenium webdriver object (specific to indeed.com)
    output: 
        - job_title, str
        - company_name, str
        - company_location, str
        - estimated_salary, str
    '''
    try:
        job_title = job_meta.find('h2', {'class':'icl-u-xs-mb--xs icl-u-xs-mt--none jobsearch-JobInfoHeader-title is-embedded'}).get_text().lstrip('new\n')
    except:
        job_title = 'No job title found'
    try:
        company_name = job_meta.find('span',{'class':'companyName'}).get_text()
    except:
        company_name = 'No Company Name'
    try:
        company_location = job_meta.find('div', {'class':'companyLocation'}).get_text()
    except:
        company_location = 'No Location'
    try:
        estimated_salary = job_meta.find('div', {'class':'metadata salary-snippet-container'}).get_text()
    except:
        estimated_salary = 'No Estimated Salary'
    return job_title, company_name, company_location, estimated_salary
```

I am expecting to pull job title, company name,location and estimated salary as defined in the function but every time I am running that function, I get empty data.

Could someone help me identify where I am going wrong

Comment: It's *scrape* **not** *scrabe*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the page is loaded by JavaScript, which BS4 can't do. If you print out your job_meta variable you will see the actual page you are getting by scraping this way.

Not sure if it's best practive, but I have been able to go around this by using chrome webdriver, which is a browser instance you can control from code, wait till the page loads and then pass the source code to your bs4 part of the code.

Alternatively you can check the Network/XHR tab on your devtools (Ctrl+Shift+I) hit refresh on the job page and view the one with the 'viewjob' in the beggining, it will have a req header, basically in the response has all the data the cards are filled out with, e.g.: https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?viewtype=embedded&jk=d75084593b7d8230&from=vjs&tk=1gjrhjcmsmsll800&continueUrl=%2Fjobs%3Fq%3DData%2Banalyst%26vjk%3Dd75084593b7d8230%26fromage%3D7%26l%3DNew%2BYork%252C%2BNY&spa=1&hidecmpheader=0